# Config::Simple and creating arrays

Tags: regex, perl

I am attempting to write a script that collects user input using getopts.  I need to be able to limit restrict the values the user can enter.  I see how to set a default value but, I have been unable to find any way to set a list of allowed values... so,

I am attempting to use `Config::Simple` to create an array from values stored in a text file to use to validate against.

#### contents of values.txt

```
ChangeCategories resolution, storm
```

#### contents of main.pl

```
#---create array from values.txt ChangeCategories

    my @chg_cats = $cfg->param("ChangeCategories");
      unlink $_ for @chg_cats;

#----grab user input via getopts
my $change_categories = $opt_c || die "Please enter a valid change category; @chg_cats";

The issue occurs when I attempt to do the pattern match, it is matching only the first value listed on the ChangeCategories line in the values.txt file.

#---pattern mathching code

my $valid_category;
chomp(@chg_cats);
foreach (@chg_cats) {
#@foreach my $line (@chg_cats) {
if(($_ =~ $change_categories) )
#if(($_ =~ m/$change_categories/) )
#if(($_ eq $change_categories) )
```

As you can see, I have tried numerous constructs to correct this and verify that I get correct matching results every time.  I am not sure if this is somehow related to 'chomping' but, I have tried every pattern I can think of.  I am a beginner to Perl and would very much appreciate any and all help.... and if anyone can tell me an easier/cleaner way to achieve this result, I would be very grateful

Comment: can you post simplified runnable code that demonstrates the problem.  You've cut out an awful lot that makes it hard to tell what would be causing the problem.

Comment: When I try it, `$_ =~ $change_categories` matches `storm` as well.